# Reading table data into a 2D array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Can anybody please help me with reading a graph data from a file and save the data into a java 2D array or List? I have been struggling

Here is the graph table:
[image]

Here is the code I have so far:

```
    Scanner matrix = new Scanner(new File("graph_input.txt"));

    String[][] arr = new String[8][];

    while(matrix.hasNextLine()){
        String[] data = matrix.nextLine().split("\\s+");

        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < arr[i].length; j++){
                arr[i][j] = Arrays.toString(arr[j]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Thank you very much for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `while` and 2 `for`s. You need only one `for`

```
Scanner matrix = new Scanner(new File("graph_input.txt"));

// Base on this you have 8 line in the matrix
String[][] arr = new String[8][];

// Read all 8 lines
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    // Get the elements of line i
    arr[i] = matrix.nextLine().split("\\s+");;
}
```

Comment: I would expect the full graph table to have 26x26 size. maybe the questioneer can clarify.

Comment: @Adder My answer is base on your example, but if you want 26 instead of 8 then use `new String[26][]` or if you don't want to set the length better use `List` (check Ganesh Chaitanya answer)

Answer (score 1):

Try the below code:

```
Scanner matrix = new Scanner(new File("graph_input.txt"));

    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> matrixArray = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

    while(matrix.hasNextLine()){
        String[] data = matrix.nextLine().split("\\s+");

        ArrayList<String> innerList = new ArrayList<String>();
        innerList.add(data[0]);
        innerList.add(data[1]);
        matrixArray.add(innerList);
    }

    System.out.println(matrixArray);
```